# Error Handling - Async Call

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, error-handling

I am creating a framework for web services used in my project. I have uploaded template in GitHub. https://github.com/vivinjeganathan/ErrorHandling

It has various layers. Layer 1 for validation. Layer 2 for formation of request. Layer 3 for the actual network call.

View Controller <----> Layer 1 <---> Layer 2 <---> Layer 3

Data flows between layers through closures, if error happens at any layer it needs to be gracefully passed to the ViewController.

I have referred to this link for error handling in async calls - http://appventure.me/2015/06/19/swift-try-catch-asynchronous-closures/
 Created a branch in the same repo - name - ErrorHandling-Method1.

I was able to transfer error from layer 3 to layer 2(Single Level - Returning response through functions in closures - as mentioned in the link). But face difficulties in transferring back across multi layers.

Can anyone assist with the sample application provided in public GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I don't think it's necessary to stack the layers the way you did, for example, by adding the validation functionality as a layer you are increasing coupling making that layer dependant of the layers below (parsing, networking, etc.), instead, why don't you separate validation to make it only dependant of the data?:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var validator = InputValidator()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      do {
         try validator.validateInput("INPUT")
         try Fetcher.requestDataWithParams("INPUT")
      }
      catch {
         handleError(error)
      }        
   }
}
```

Now the validation functionality is not dependant of the other layers, so communication would flow like this:

View Controller <---> ParsingLayer <---> NetworkingLayer

I did rename the layers but they are not necessarily have to be like this, you can add or remove layers.

I think is going to be kind of complicated if I try to explain my approach, so I'm going to give an example using the previous layers, first the bottom layer:

```
class NetworkingLayer {
   class func requestData(params: AnyObject, completion: (getResult: () throw -> AnyObject) -> Void) -> Void {
      session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, urlResponse, var error) in
         if let error = error {
            completion(getResult: { throw error })
         } else {
            completion(getResult: { return data })
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have omitted some sections of code, but the idea is to do any necessary step to make the layer work (create session, etc.) and to always communicate back through the completion closure; a layer on top would look like this:

```
class ParsingLayer {
   class func requestObject(params: AnyObject, completion: (getObject: () throw -> CustomObject) -> Void) -> Void {
      NetworkingLayer.requestData(params, completion: { (getResult) -> Void in
         do {
            let data = try getResult()
            let object = try self.parseData(data)
            completion(getObject: { return object })
         }
         catch {
            completion(getObject: { throw error })
         }
      })
   } 
}
```

Notice that the completion closures are not the same, since every layer adds functionality, the returned object can change, also notice that the code inside the `do` statement can fail in two ways, first if the network call fails and then if the data from the networking layer cannot be parsed; again the communication to the layer on top is always done through the completion closure.

Finally the ViewController can call the next layer using the closure expected by the Parsing layer in this case, and is able to handle errors originated in any layer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   do {
      try validator.validateInput("INPUT")
      try ParsingLayer.requestObject("INPUT", completion: { (getObject) in
      do {
         let object = try getObject()
         try self.validator.validateOutput(object)
         print(object)
      }
      catch {
         self.handleError(error)
      }
   })
   catch {
      handleError(error)
   }        
}
```

Notice that there is a `do catch` inside the completion closure, this is necessary since the call is made asynchronously, now that the response has gone through all the layers and have actually change to be of a more specialised type you can even validate the result without having the necessity to make a layer for the validation functionality.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I liked your approach of eliminating a later for validation. But the place, let data = try getResult()[In PARSING LAYER] & let object = try getObject() [In View Controller] is not very convenient. Personally i feel NSNotification is cleaner and simpler. Can you tell if you have any advantage of your approach over the notifications? Because i don't find any. I would be happy to know it and refactor my code accordingly.

Comment: In this case the parsing layer is dependant of the networking layer, the communication has a 1 to 1 relationship, there is really no necessity to use a broadcasting system, some of the disadvantages to use notifications are: - No compile time to checks to ensure that notifications are correctly handled by observers. -Not very traceable (hard to debug) - Adds another layer of complexity -Notification Names, and UserInfo dictionary keys need to be known by both the observers and the controllers - Since everyone can subscribe to the notification there is probably a poor encapsulation of data

Comment: I should have say that I have used the approach in my answer in a couple of apps, I have a networking layer that communicates back to a parsing layer which communicates back to a repository layer that is finally used by the presentation layer (View Controllers) and services layer; the networking layer only handles the communication with the server, the Parsing layer converts the JSON response to Model objects using introspection and generics, the Repository layer handles URL's and parameters and all data and errors flow through the chain without any problems, without notifications.

Comment: The handler might seem complex, but it is only complex to look and understand at first, in the end is no more that a closure that contains another closure, there is really no much overhead because every layer receives one closure (passed as a reference) and there is only two calls per layer: first you call completion to send the closure with the result or error, and then the next layer calls that closure to receive the result or error; on the other hand you make a call to the Notification Center with the result or error, the NC performs a search and makes another call to the listener (layer)

Comment: Besides, I'm not sure but I think that the use of notifications would result in a system with low cohesion

Comment: thanks. I am convinced to go ahead with your implementation.

Comment: @vivin Encapsulating objects into functions is an interesting idea, but you should be aware that data objects computed by asynchronous functions will usually need to be passed to different execution environments. That means, if you care about "thread-safety" this approach is problematic: it is only thread-safe when all completion handlers will be executed in the same execution environment as the call-site. Usually, this is not the case.

Comment: I might be wrong, and I'd like know if I am, but I disagree with @CouchDeveloper, the creation and modification of the returned objet happens only once and the closure that creates and first captures the object is gone immediately after the completion closure finishes (last statement), if you send back a closure that captures an object to a different thread that closure exists in the new thread capturing the object previously created and cannot be modified by the previous thread because that first closure will be destroyed; so the object exist in one thread only now.

Comment: @juanjo The problem is, that captured objects will be created and initialized in thread A, which writes to memory, and later it will be read from thread B. Without synchronization primitives this can lead to bogus reads due to operation reordering. There's no guarantee that reads on thread B will happen _after_ the corresponding writes to the same memory in thread A, and that the memory writes will be visible in any other thread.

Comment: var string = "Hi"
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print(string)
} // lets say this is executed in thread A, are you saying that the print statement executed in thread B is not guaranteed to execute after the creation of the variable?

Comment: Ok, there might be a problem due to the fact that the network call success closure is executed in another thread, my bad, but is not a particular problem of the approach described, it is a problem inherent to any asynchronous call which can be easily solved changing threads (usually the main thread) in any layer

Comment: @juanjo There's no threading issue in your current code: all completion handlers and the passed "getter" closures will execute on the same thread (It's a non-issue on strongly-ordered memory models anyway).  I'm just wondering what happens when you submit a closure importing the getter closure via `dispatch_async` within a completion handler... But, I would guess, that dispatch lib will setup the required memory barriers correctly. So, after thinking more deeply about your approach, I can say, it's possible to execute completion handlers on a different queue - and it's still "thread-safe" ;)

Comment: @juanjo, I have a problem in code refactoring with the suggested approach. I have made it as a separate question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638070/dealing-with-closures-make-code-more-generic. Can u just advise me on that please?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use notifications passing the NSError as the object of the notification in the layers and observe the notification in the view controller.

In the layers:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ErrorEncounteredNotification", object: error)
```

In the view controller

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "errorEncountered:", name: "ErrorEncounteredNotification", object: nil)
```

the selector method:

```
func errorEncountered(notification: NSNotification!) {
    let error: NSError! = notification.object as! NSError
    NSLog("error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Why would you post a notification instead of catching the error getting thrown anyway?

Answer (score 3):

You correctly identified a nasty problem with error handling in asynchronous code.

It seems to be easy with synchronous functions - which just return an error code, or have an extra error parameter, or use the new Swift `throws` syntax. Here is an *synchronous* function:

```
func computeSome() throws -> Some
```

And this is a viable function signature for an *asynchronous* function:

```
func computeSomeAsync(completion: (Some?, NSError?) -> ())
```

The asynchronous function returns `Void` and does not throw. If it fails, it calls its completion function with the error parameter set.

However, completion handlers become quickly cumbersome, especially in nested code.

The solution is to use a *Future*:

```
func computeSomeAsync() -> Future<Some>
```

This function is asynchronous and does not throw - and returns a *Future*. So, what's a future?

Well a future represents the *eventual* result of an asynchronous function. When you call the asynchronous function, it immediately returns and you get a *placeholder* for the result. This, called a *future*, will be eventually *completed* by the underlying background task that computes the value.

When the underlying task eventually succeeded, this future contains the computed value of the function. When it failed it will contain the error.

Depending on the actual implementation and the API of a Future Library, you can obtain the result by registering *continuations*:

```
let future = computeSomeAsync()

future.onSuccess { value in
    print("Value: \(value)")
}


future.onFailure { error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

It may look weird at first, but you can do awesome things with futures:

```
fetchUser(id).flatMap { user in
    fetchProfileImage(user.profileImageUrl).flatMap { image in
        cacheImage(image)
    }
}
.onFailure { error in
    print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
}
```

The above statement is asynchronous - as well as function `fetchUser`, `fetchProfileImage` and `cacheImage`. Error handling included.

Comment: Thanks. But i am not completely getting your approach(future function & its advantages). If you don't mind can u just alter my code in the github so that i can play around with.

Comment: @vivin You may clone [FutureLib](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/FutureLib) and read the README file. Open the project in Xcode and create a new Playgrounds file and try to reproduce and understand the simple samples in a playground. Take a look at the existing playground to get sample functions which simulate network requests. Possibly take a look also at [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) which is another quite awesome implementation of Scala-style futures and promises.

Answer (score 2):

Why declare your method throws if you never throw or even try to catch? You could throw the errors using the throwable declaration through all the layers, and even change the throwable type at each level.

UPDATE: Didnt think of throwing dont work in async operations. Using NSNotification is one good route, or you could take a look at [RXSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) or similar to solve it too. My personal recommendation would be to use RxSwift. This keeps you out of callback hell, which you are currently travelling down into.

Comment: This is not possible, if your closures are asynchronous ;)